# Can't connect to another PC on the same network on a particular port

Tags: postgresql, port, portforwarding

I am trying to access the postgresql service which is running on my computer (which as you can see in the picture, it is running), from another computer on the same network.

[image]

On another computer, I am trying to access port 5432 (on which this service runs) by typing in `telnet 192.168.2.102 5432`; however it fails to connect. Can someone tell me what the problem might be please?

Comment: Could be a thousand different things, but the 2 most likely are that your firewall is blocking it, or Postgres is running on a different port (in that order)

Comment: Firewall is switched off. How can I know on which port is this service running please? I typed `netstat -a` but I couldn't see it

Comment: What error does it fail with?

Comment: Look closely at postgresql config files. Especially at `listen_addresses`, `port` variables. Also check you `pg_hba` for addresses, allowed to connect.

Comment: @user1135357, if `netstat -a | findstr 5432` does not show any results, then Postgres is not listening on that port

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read [`this`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-connection.html) and [`this`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) pages of the manual to set up connections to the postgresql server correctly.

Take a closer look at `listen_addresses`, `port` configuration in `postgresql.conf` and security settings in `pg_hba.conf`.

And dont forget to restart your server after you've updated the config files.